# How does Probability behave as $N\to\infty$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, limits

In a question of Probability, I got the answer
$$\frac{\sum_{j=0}^N(j/N)^{n+1}}{\sum_{j=0}^N(j/N)^{n}}$$

Now I have to prove when $N\to\infty$ above expression approximately is $\frac {n+1}{n+2}.$ No idea how to proceed, kindly help in this regards.

Comment: Do you know anything about Riemann sums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=0}^N(j/N)^{n+1}\to \int_{0}^1 x^{n+1}\,dx$$

and:

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=0}^N(j/N)^{n}\to \int_{0}^1 x^{n}\,dx$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{N \to  \infty}\frac{\sum_{j=0}^N(j/N)^{n+1}}{\sum_{j=0}^N(j/N)^{n}}=\frac{ \lim_{N \to  \infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=0}^N(j/N)^{n+1}}{ \lim_{N \to  \infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=0}^N(j/N)^{n}}$$ $$=\frac{\int_0^1 \! {x^{n+1} \, \mathrm{dx}}}{ \int_0^1 \! {x^n \, \mathrm{dx}}}=\frac{\left[ \frac{x^{n+2}}{n+2}\right]_0^1}{\left[ \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]_0^1}$$$$=\frac{n+1}{n+2}$$